# Save and get media from MongoDB database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have a MERN Stack in which the user upload one of the 4 types of files: .pdf, .jpeg, .psd, .ai and I used FileReader to save it as buffer to mongoDB Database. I want to render it back to my React app (automatically download the file) on click. 'react-pdf' didnt help because the data which comes back from the database is buffer type and hence it shows 'Failed to load PDF' How do I solve this issue for all file types?

Answer (score 0):

What I think there is nothing wrong with your client-side part the main cause of this is how you are storing it into DB

To store files in MongoDB you should try to use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/gridfs/)

You can find some tutorials about working with GridFS ([example](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle2.html)).

Check your MongoDB Driver's API and try to implement it in your project

Comment: I stored images as Buffer data in database and that worked out pretty good. Why does it not work with any other file type?

Comment: so you are facing problem with PDF only

Comment: The problem is that when you upload an image in buffer type and use <img src={}/> in the client side, it renders the picture for you but this isnt applicable for any other file types. In GridFs I'll have to store the file somewhere else but I have a complex structure of folders and I want to save the file there only.

Comment: I think there is some problem with your PDF buffer can you please share your code

Comment: const file=event.target.files[0]
        const fileReader= new FileReader()
        fileReader.addEventListener('load',()=>{
                       const fileUrl= fileReader.result
         })         fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)

Comment: How do I save a downloadUrl into the database so that it on client side it directly downloads the file from that url and I dont have to render it at all?